# Count pair of two column value in Sql which are match in tables

Tags: sql, database

I have two table

**Brands Table**

It is a list of brand_id chosen by the Particular user.

```
id_autoicrement | user_id |  brand_id 

              1 |   5     |    7
              2 |   5     |    3
              3 |   5     |    1
              4 |   9     |    3
              5 |   9     |    7
              6 |   2     |    3
              7 |   2     |    7
              8 |   4     |    3
```

**Product Table**

It is a list of product_id chosen by the Particular user.

```
id_autoicrement | user_id |  product_id 

              1 |   5     |    4
              2 |   5     |    1
              3 |   5     |    2
              4 |   9     |    1
              5 |   9     |    4
              6 |   2     |    1
              7 |   2     |    4
              8 |   4     |    1
```

**Edit**

Sorry i got it wrong. 
I want the list of brand_id and product_id which are taken by same number of users whose pair of brand_id and product_id values are same.  above tables are same.

```
User A                              User B

brand_id  | product_id               brand_id  | product_id 

       1  | 2                               1  | 3
          | 3                               2
```

Same number of pairs by different user...

```
User A has two pairs                              User B has two paris

brand_id 1 and product_id 2                       brand_id 1 and product_id 3
brand_id 1 and product_id 3                       brand_id 2 and product_id 3
```

Result should be like

```
brand_id  product_id -> combination
  1          2       -> 1
  1          3       -> 2
  2          3       -> 1
```

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Three people have answered your original question. While that question may not be relevant to you, it still seems to make sense and may have value for other people. Please consider rolling back this question to the original version and creating a separate question for your actual problem.

Comment: @AndriyM i appologize again. I have got it wrong in the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join the two tables by user only, group by brand and product and you're done.

```
select product_id, brand_id, count(*)
from brands b
inner join product p on p.user_id = b.user_id 
group by product_id, brand_id;
```

The join creates one record per user-product-brand combination. Then by grouping by product and brand, you count users who chose the product-brand combination.

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f868a/2.

Comment: See my edit please and sorry for changing the question @Thorsten Kettner

Comment: I don't see how this is different from your original question. You want all chosen product-brand combinations and know how many users chose that. This is (still) what my query does. Can you explain what is different between my solution and your expected results?

Comment: I don't need p.user_id = b.user_id  statement. Count from all the user's whose pairs are same not as you did whose p.user_id =b.user_id .. I need the count of user having same pair of brand_id and product_id without check that their p.user_id =b.user_id

Comment: I think you are wrong. Did you even look into the SQL fiddle? User A chose brand 1 and products 2 and 3. By selecting from both tables with `p.user_id = b.user_id` I get the combinations 1-2 and 1-3 for the user. And I will get 1-3 and 2-3 for user B, thus getting a count of 2 for the combination 1-3, just as you describe in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query

```
select product_id,brand_id , product_users as count from 
(
select count(user_id) product_users, product_id from product_table
) a,
(
select count(user_id) brand_users, brand_id from brand_table
) b
where a.product_users = b.brand_users;
```